# How to send eventdata and event name from spring boot to angular?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, events, event-handling

I am developing chat application in Angular and spring boot. I am using `EventSource` in Angular and `ApplicationEventPublisher` interface in Spring boot. Now, I want to send event-data and event-name from spring boot to angular so that `eventSource.addListener("eventName", () => {})` will catch the event based on the event-name. Please tell me how to send event-data and event-name from spring boot to angular.
My spring-boot controller:

```
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RestController
public class MessageController {

    @Autowired
    MessageService messageService;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationEventPublisher applicationEventPublisher;

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = "/event/")
    public void getEvent(@RequestHeader(value = "Content-Type", defaultValue = "text/event-stream")) 
    {
        logger.info("AWSTranslateController:: getEvent() method /event");
        MessageEvent messageEvent = new MessageEvent (this, "receiver3", response);
        applicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(messageEvent );
    }
}
```

springboot MessageEvent POJO:

```
public class MessageEvent extends ApplicationEvent{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Object eventResponse;
    private String eventName;

    public MessageEvent(Object source, String eventName, Object eventResponse) {
        super(source);
        this.eventName = eventName;
       this.eventResponse = eventResponse;
    }

    public Object getEventResponse() {
        return eventResponse;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a listening service on the angular side, probably the solution is with WebSocket concept. Once your socket port is ready to receive the request, u can ping the event with the message.

[An example with WebSocket and angular is here](https://medium.com/oril/spring-boot-websockets-angular-5-f2f4b1c14cee)